# Page crash after converting to Angular Universal (SSR)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

First, apologies for the vague title, I can't make it more specific without going super long. So I have this confirmation page after the user make payment on a 3rd party payment gateway (think PayPal), it bounce back to my site with query params. Then I present the page with all the info (payment method x is success etc etc). That page is working fine with non-SSR site.

The relevant codes:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-result',
  templateUrl: './payment-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-result.component.css']
})
export class PaymentResultComponent implements OnInit {
  isBusy: boolean;
  data: PaymentResult;
  success: boolean;
  isPaymentInformationBusy = true;
  paymentInformation: PaymentInformationResult[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private requestService: RequestService,
    private modalService: ModalService
  ) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
      if (params) {
        this.getData(params?.merchantOrderId);
        this.success = params?.resultCode === '00';
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  getData(transactionNo: string): void {
    this.isBusy = true;
    this.requestService.get<PurchaseTransactionResult>(
      'purchase-transaction',
      obj => {
        this.data = obj;
        this.getPaymentInformation(obj?.PaymentMethodInformation?.ID);
      },
      failed => {
        console.log(failed);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        this.isBusy = false;
      },
      {TransactionNo: decodeURIComponent(transactionNo)}
    );
  }

  getPaymentInformation(id: string): void {
    this.isPaymentInformationBusy = true;
    this.requestService.get<PaymentInformationResult[]>(
      `purchase-transaction/payment-method-information/${id}`,
      obj => {
        this.paymentInformation = obj;
        ScriptLoader.loadScript('/assets/js/payment.js', 'payment');
      },
      failed => {
        console.log(failed);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(failed);
      },
      () => {
        this.isPaymentInformationBusy = false;
      });
  }

  getArray(count: number): any[] {
    return new Array(count);
  }
}
```

The crash error message:

```bash
/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:111913
              throw error;
              ^

TypeError: (element || document.body).getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at reflow (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:218104:37)
    at ngbRunTransition.animation (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:226946:11)
    at ngbRunTransition (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:218181:17)
    at Object.next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:226944:7)
    at ConsumerObserver.__webpack_modules__.3317.ConsumerObserver.next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:89909:33)
    at SafeSubscriber.__webpack_modules__.3317.Subscriber._next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:89876:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.__webpack_modules__.3317.Subscriber.next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:89847:18)
    at /Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:95558:32
    at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:92037:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.__webpack_modules__.3317.Subscriber.next (/Users/marko/appname/web/dist/web/server/main.js:89847:18)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
```

The error message is what throws me. It seems like I'm trying to call `getBoundingClientRect` function but I don't have that in any of my codes.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely your webserver doesn't allow AJAX calls to the API on the very same server. You'll have to use something like [`SupplyData`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering/Services/ISpaPrerenderingService.cs#L6), whatever it's called for your backend stack. What backend are you using?

Comment: @Pieterjan .net core. All API calls go through there. the angular universal is still running on my local machine. And it works on the non SSR site. My current idea for workaround is calling the API from the client side.

Comment: Ah no. On second read, yeah Node doesn't have the `window` object. So you'll have to prevent the code which calls `getBoundingClientRect` from being triggered using `if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your question. The issue is that you're using something (I guess it's **ngbRunTransition**) that calls `getBoundingClientRect`.

Obviously this method isn't known to Node since Node doesn't have the `window` object. You'll have to look what component/directive in your application is calling the `getBoundingClientRect` method, and remove it from the DOM using `*ngIf`, similarily as the other answer.

```
export class ArtistShowComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    this.isServerSide = isPlatformServer(platformId);
  }

  isServerSide: boolean;
}
```

In html

```
<!-- Remove the div from the DOM -->
<div [ngbRunTransition]="'slide'" *ngIf="!isServerSide"></div>
```

You'll have to find out what component uses the transition, and remove this from the DOM if server-side.

Comment: This lead me to the right direction, since it worked on non SSR side, I just tried to call getData if platform is browser. And it works! Basically the answer is `if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) this.getData(params?.merchantOrderId);`, that's it. I'm betting that I can fix a lot of other issues with this too (I'm still very new at Angular if it's obvious). Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably fix your issue by not sending AJAX calls during SSR. Therefore you have to use the

- [`SupplyData`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4f838e2337b764ecf4bd06baacf203542a0a8338/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L162) method if you're using ASP.NET Core 3.1 ([example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/72dcf83565d5cbcf2d1e6e62f17282c5a5881e48/Demo/Demo.Web/Startup.cs#L109) however this lambda should not be async)
- [`ISpaPrerenderingService.OnSupplyData`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering/Services/ISpaPrerenderingService.cs#L6) method if you're using ASP.NET 6 ([example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L143), this method can be `async` and you're able to inject services properly)

After this, you'll receive the data through the [main.server.ts](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.server.ts#L13) where you can create a provider containing them.

Then, in your page, you can [inject this provider](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/pages/artist/show/show.component.ts) and use it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'artist-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.scss']
})
export class ArtistShowComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private artistService: ArtistService, private route: ActivatedRoute, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, @Inject('ARTIST') private artistInj: Artist) {
    if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
      this.artist = artistInj;
    } else {
      this.artistService.getArtist(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')));
    }
  }

  artist: Artist | null = null;
}
```

My suggestion somehow, would be to only pass a single object all the way from .NET Core to the angular provider. Makes it easier when the app grows.

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting that it's actually server issue. Currently the app is running angular through .net core, but I plan on moving away from it. Hence I'm decoupling them (while also updating a bunch of things).

Comment: Well yeah, some environments don't allow ajax calls to themselves during SSR. It doesn't really have anything to do with .NET specifically. I have the same behavior on my live environment